# how to convert string to bytes in javascript

Tags: javascript

I  have a string value like `1,2,3` and i need convert to byte value like `[1,2,3]`?

how to bind  javascript byte  to  C# `Byte[]` array

```
const file = e.files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file.rawFile);
reader.onload = function () {
     var strBytes = new Uint8Array(reader.result).join();
     var byte=???;
}
```

thanks

Comment: `.join()` converts the `Uint8Array` to a string. If you don’t want a string, don’t call `.join()`.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a `Uint8Array`, the data is stored as bytes, which is exactly what you are looking for here.

What you've done when using `.join()` is to create them as strings.

Just remove the `.join` and you will have an array of bytes:

```
var strBytes = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
```

Comment: i first try new Uint8Array(reader.result) but  not bind to c# byte

Comment: What do you mean *but not bind to c# byte*? Can you provide an example? An error message?

Comment: in byte send to asp.net web api with property        public System.Byte[] FileData { get; set; }  and not bind to my FileData property